# db2 how to configure external tables using extbl_location, extbl_strict_io

Tags: db2

db2 how to configure external tables using extbl_location, extbl_strict_io. Could you please give insert example for system table how to set up this parameters. I need to create external table and upload data to external table.
I need to know how to configure parameters extbl_location, extbl_strict_io.

I created table like this.

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE textteacher(ID int, Name char(50), email varchar(255)) USING ( DATAOBJECT 'teacher.csv' FORMAT TEXT CCSID 1208 DELIMITER '|' REMOTESOURCE 'LOCAL' SOCKETBUFSIZE 30000 LOGDIR '/tmp/logs' );

and tried to upload data to it.

insert into textteacher (ID,Name,email) select id,name,email from teacher;

and get exception [428IB][-20569] The external table operation failed due to a problem with the corresponding data file or diagnostic files. File name: "teacher.csv". Reason code: "1".. SQLCODE=-20569, SQLSTATE=428IB, DRIVER=4.26.14

If I correct understand documentation parameter extbl_location should pointed directory where data will save. I suppose full directory will showed like
$extbl_location+'/'+teacher.csv

I found some documentation about error
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-resolve-sql20569n-error-external-table-operation

I tried to run command in docker command line.
/opt/ibm/db2/V11.5/bin/db2 get db cfg | grep -i external
but does not  information about external any tables.

Comment: The two configuration parameters that you mention (extbl_location and extbl_strict_io) are __optional__  and have defaults as documented and their purpose is to adjust how the `create external table` DDL works. But,  what is your `create external table` syntax, what is the file-format for your data file that you want to map via `create external table` ?

Comment: I created table like this. 

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE textteacher(ID int, Name char(50), email varchar(255)) USING
(
DATAOBJECT 'teacher.csv'
FORMAT TEXT CCSID 1208
DELIMITER '|'
REMOTESOURCE 'LOCAL'
SOCKETBUFSIZE 30000
LOGDIR '/tmp/logs'
);
and tried to upload data to it.
insert into textteacher (ID,Name,email)  select id,name,email from teacher;
 and get exception
[428IB][-20569] The external table operation failed due to a problem with the corresponding data file or diagnostic files. File name: "teacher.csv". Reason code: "1".. SQLCODE=-20569, SQLSTATE=428IB, DRIVER=4.26.14

Comment: If I correct understand documentation parameter extbl_location should pointed directory where data will save. I suppose full directory will showed like $extbl_location+'/'+teacher.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE statement](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-create-external-table):

> **file-name**
> ...
> When both the REMOTESOURCE option is set to LOCAL (this is its default value) and the extbl_strict_io configuration parameter is set
> to NO, the path to the external table file is an absolute path and
> must be one of the paths specified by the extbl_location configuration
> parameter. **Otherwise, the path to the external table file is relative
> to the path that is specified by the extbl_location configuration
> parameter followed by the authorization ID of the table definer**. For
> example, **if extbl_location is set to /home/xyz and the authorization
> ID of the table definer is user1, the path to the external table file
> is relative to /home/xyz/user1/**.

So, If you use relative path to a file as `teacher.csv`, you must set `extbl_strict_io` to `YES`.

> **For an unload operation, the following conditions apply:**
>
> - If the file exists, it is overwritten.
> - Required permissions:
>   **If the external table is a named external table, the owner must have read and write permission for the directory of this file.**
>   If the external table is transient, the authorization ID of the statement must have read and write permission for the directory of this file.

Moreover you must create a sub-directory equal to your username (in lowercase) which is owner of this table in the directory specified in `extbl_location` and ensure, that this user (not the instance owner) has `rw` permission to this sub-directory.

**Update:**

To setup presuming, that `user1` runs this INSERT statement.

```
sudo mkdir -p /home/xyz/user1
# user1 must have an ability to cd to this directory
sudo chown user1:$(id -gn user1) /home/xyz/user1

db2 connect to mydb
db2 update db cfg using extbl_location /home/xyz extbl_strict_io YES
```

Comment: Thank you Mark. Could you please clarify how to set up extbl_strict_io, extbl_location both this parameters? Is this  insert to system tables ?

Comment: @SashaCorn Look at the updated answer.